# Error when finding unique words in txt file

Tags: python-3.x, unique

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to find all the unique words in a txt file, however I seem to be stuck on this error that occurred after I coded the line that removes all punctuation from the list.

Here is my code so far:

```
import string
a = open('blank.txt')      
def main():
    check = []
    for line in a:
      lines = line.lower()
      words = line.split()
      for word in words:
        if word not in check:
            check.append(word)
      check = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in check]
      check = [s for s in x if s]
check.sort()
print(check)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

After running this I'm getting an error message: if word not in check:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'check' referenced before assignment
```

Was wondering if anyone had any ideas that could help. Thanks

Comment: This code can't give you the error you say it gives you. First, it's not indented properly and won't run at all because of that. Second, the error you're getting is about local variables will and so be given only when there ARE local variables, which there are not, because your code contains no function for variables to be local TO. Please post the actual code you are running, or a simplified version that runs but gives the same message.

Comment: As @kindall wrote, this code doesn't run as expected. The error you are getting (UnboundLocalError) can in some instances be due to a file being empty when iterating over it. Can you post the updated code and confirm this is also happening when reading a file that isn't empty? This is an assumption based on the name of your file ('blank.txt') and prior experience with a similar situation.

Comment: yeah i change the file name to blank on purpose and the indentation might be the issue. Is it possible you could point out the indention problems. Also have this code inside a def main() function not sure if thats also causing a problem. @kindall

Comment: and @SébastienLavoie

Comment: @Sam There are a few issues here. You need to indent your last line (`main()`) so it becomes part of the if statement. You also need to define `check` inside your `main()` function (move `check = []` at the beginning of the `main()` function). `check.sort()` and your print statement should also be inside your `main()` function at the end. You need to have a valid reference in your list comprehension: `c for c in line if c` and later `s for s in line`. When you have `s for s in x if s`, be aware that `x` is not defined.

Comment: You also need to indent your two list comprehensions one more step so that you can apply the check for each line, as it is currently not part of your `for` loop.

Comment: ok and yes I just caught on to the x however when i changed it to check I think it created an indefinite loop. I'm new to familiar with how this line of code physically works as I just implemented to get rid of the blank list items that were caused by the line above that gets rid of all the punctuation. Any suggestions. @SébastienLavoie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be close enough to what you are trying to achieve based on your existing code:

```
import string


def main():
    # `check` needs to be inside your function to be accessible.
    # → You can read about "variable scope" if in doubt.
    # You also need to read your file inside your function
    # if you don't pass any argument to it.
    # Note that it is generally better to use a 'with' block
    # to automatically close your file when you are done with it.

    check = []
    with open('blank.txt') as a:
        content = a.read().lower().split()
        for word in content:
            if word not in check:
                check.append(word)
        check = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation)
                  for s in check]
        check = [s for s in check if s]
        print(check)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  # This has to be indented
```

If `blank.txt` contains the following text:

> I'm working on a project where I'm trying to find all the unique words in a txt file, however I seem to be stuck on this error that occurred after I coded the line that removes all punctuation from the list.

Your output will be:

```
['im', 'working', 'on', 'a', 'project', 'where', 'trying', 'to', 'find', 'all', 'the', 'unique', 'words', 'in', 'txt', 'file', 'however', 'i', 'seem', 'be', 'stuck', 'this', 'error', 'that', 'occurred', 'after', 'coded', 'line', 'removes', 'punctuation', 'from', 'list']
```

If your file is empty, you will simply get an empty list.